# server won't share files within new domain

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, network-share, file-sharing

I have a windows server 2008 (dc now called server1) and a windows server 2003 (files now called server2).

The previous DC crashed and I created a new one (server1), same domain name, same hostname. The profiles share is located on server2. I removed the old domain from server2, did a reboot, add it to the new domain, and did a final reboot.

But I can't access the filesever from server1 at all. I get the error

`\\server2\profiles is not accessible. You might not have tpermission to use this network resource. Contact the administrator of this server to find out if you have access permissions. This Server's clock is not synchronized with the primary domain controller's cloc`k

when I try to acces it from the network screen or when I type the \server2\profileshare address.

When I remove the server2 from the domain, then I can access the shares from out server1..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you actually read the message and checked that the clocks are in sync? Machines on a Windows domain have to be within a certain tolerance of each other (5 minutes from memory but I'm not 100% sure) otherwise the Kerberos process which underpins Active Directory assumes that something dodgy is going off and bars connections.

As a starting point make sure both machines times are synced (use one of the NTP pool addresses if unsure) and make sure the timezones are set correctly on both machines. They don't actually have to be synced to each other, but they do both have to be within the 5 minute window so if you sync them to an external source, sync them to the same one.

Comment: OMG... What a noob mistake. :S Thx man!